# SP Online: Can you map a crawled property to a refinable managed property using export/import or PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, xml, pnp-powershell

We have a SPFx solution and a requirement for which we need to map a crawled property to a RefinableDateXX managed property. We would like to ensure the proper search schema upon deployment, even if as a separate step. We also need to make sure that we don't overwrite any previous custom mappings added on those properties.

I see everywhere that you can export/import the search settings using either the UI or PowerShell PnP. However, the exported XML offers no information about the managed properties and their mappings. Our original idea was first to export the schema on the client tenant, append our crawled property to the managed property we would need, and then reimport. Is there any way we can achieve this?

If not, is there any way that we can add a new crawled property mapping to a refinable managed property using PowerShell / XML import?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, sharepoint online only allow to import / export xml for these search mapping configuration, either via UI or powershell.